# Unit test optimization program - Pyomo

Tags: python, unit-testing, mathematical-optimization, pyomo

I am implementing several optimization programs with pyomo.

So far I have written some integration tests with `unittest` on optimal objective value and optimal variable values.

I would like to write unit tests for each objective and constraints to make sure they are correctly implemented. What's the correct way to do it?

Comment: I think this would be highly dependent on both the type of problem you are working *and* if you have certain scenarios for which you know the correct (optimal) answer.  If you have some combination of inputs that binds one of the constraints, you could run that, inspect the constraint ant OBJ function and then double the input driving the bound constraint and make sure nothing changes, etc.  Another strategy that I've found useful is to break up the obj function (assuming it is mildly complex) into into expressions and then inspect/test them individually

Comment: @AirSquid Thanks for your comment. I am not sure I understand the part " double the *input driving the bound constraint* and make sure *nothing changes*, etc". Could you please give some precisions?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure I said that correctly...  Let me post a more complete notion as an answer...

Comment: Instead of checking individual constraints (very difficult in my opinion as we are solving systems of equations where an individual constraint is less meaningful), I usually focus on adding a ton of tests on the input data and on the solution. Every time something strange happens, try to add tests that would have prevented this.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple strategies here that might be useful, and I'd be curious if other folks have other contributions.

1. If you know the objective value for a particular scenario/dataset,
   that is a no-brainer to unit-test that value +/- some delta against
   your solution
2. If you have some constraint that should be binding, you can make up a set of inputs to ensure that it binds.  Say for example you have a toy model that has 2 inputs:  number of trucks and gallons of gas and the objective is to move some packages in the trucks, based on some logical constraints on truck capacity, number of trucks, gas for trips.  You could:

- as a baseline, give the model 1 truck and enough gas for 1 trip and
  ensure the solution delivers 1 truckload of pkgs
- add in a bunch of extra trucks and ensure the objective remains the    same (bound by gas constraint)
- put in 0 trucks / 0 gas and see that nothing happens.  <-- Always good idea! :)

3. If you have a complicated objective function, you could break it up into expressions and inspect or do assertion checks on those elements.  Continuing with the previous example, if you had an objective that had packages delivered, penalties for trips & gas used you could...

```
pkgs_delivered = sum(...)
trip_count = sum(...)
gas_used = sum(...)
w_1, w_2 = # some weights for penalties...

mdl.obj = pyo.Objective(expr= pkgs_delivered - w_1 * trip_count - w_2 * gas_used, sense=pyo.maximize)
```

Then you can peel apart these elements in your unit tests (if it makes sense) and check their values as they are `pyomo` `expressions`

```
assertEqual(trip_count.value(), 8, 'this setup should have 8 trips')
```